# Run Solver NOT on active sheet (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that I am using to solve a system of non-linear equations, and then display the solution on a chart. The chart has a large amount of content (basically the result of solving the system of equations for a few standard cases), which references a table of about 1200 cells. That content is static, and so for aesthetics I keep the calculations table on sheet1 and graph on sheet2.

Then on the graph sheet I allow user input to two cells which are referenced in the calculations on sheet1 to build three dynamic instances of the system of equations. Pretty lightweight for solver to handle one at a time.

I use a Worksheet_Change event on sheet2 to watch for the user to modify those two cells and then it calls a sub that runs the solver.

The event code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If (Target.Address = "$C$3") Or (Target.Address = "$D$3") Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        SolverEQN 178, 180

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The Solver code:

```
Sub SolverEQN(rw, rwend As Integer)
    Dim iter As Integer

    For iter = rw To rwend

        If Sheets(1).Cells(iter, 14) <> 0 Then
            SolverReset
            SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=False
            SolverOK SetCell:="'Sheet1'!$N$" & iter, MaxMinVal:="3", ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="'Sheet1'!$H$" & iter
            SolverSolve True
        End If

    Next iter

End Sub
```

Here is where the problem is encountered. Solver runs on sheet2, despite my assigning it to run on sheet1, meaning the system of equations don't exist where they should and solver quickly optimizes to 0 = 0 in the middle of my active sheet.

There are two workarounds that I've found:

1 - Set my activesheet to be sheet1 before running solver and then set activesheet back to sheet2 after solver runs. This causes a short pause and screen flicker, so the experience would not be 'seamless' for a user.

2 - Solve the dynamic system of equations on the graph sheet and hide them in a crude way (white font, stuff them behind my graph, YUCK!).

I will handle this with option 2 if I have to, but do you creative folks have any ideas on how to keep the calculations on my calculations sheet?

Input much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: you could use workaround 1 with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` then change sheet and run the solver. If everything is finished, go back to your sheet and set `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` again. (No flicker)

Comment: @DirkReichel I appreciate the feedback, but you'll notice the first thing that I do after the event determines the correct cell changed, is set screenupdating to false. I'm still getting the flicker though. Because updating is false this is a surprising result.

Comment: I assume that this is a part of the solver itself. There are multiple actions which cannot prevented. But depending on the complexity of your equations, your best solution will be a sub which "searches" for the solution. Or even better (but probably not possible for us) is a mathematical equation which directly outputs the numbers you need. However: without a sheet and some example data it will be hard to help to do it this way. Also for workaround 2: setting the number format of the cells to "`;;;`" will be easier. It will look like it's empty except for the formula bar if selected.

Comment: @DirkReichel Thanks for these thoughts. I believe you are right that Solver is taking actions that cannot be prevented. Of course! This makes sense given it has its own libraries external of the excel application. As for an expression to compute the numbers instead of optimizing, that just won't be possible. The equations I have are transcendental so no clean inverse exists. I'll probably just write my own optimization code and call that, maybe overkill but at least I get control that way. Thanks for all of your input (and neat formatting trick, very cool!). Cheers.

Comment: You are welcome ;)